# Facing word wrap issues with HighCharts chart.renderer.text

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I have almost no experience in browser side and I have been debugging this issue since a day now and just not able to solve it.
I have a box that shows a dynamic text whenever we point to a particular object as a tooltip. The problem here is it is not wrapping up the next into multiple lines due to which it is getting clipped.

Here is my code

```
var html_comment= (this.getAttribute('comment')).toString();
            html_comment = html_comment.replace(/(?:\\r\\n|\r|\\n| \\n)/g, '<br />');
            if(activityCount > 1){
              $('.highcharts-tooltip').hide();
              html_comment = numberOfActivityHeader;        
            }
            text = chart.renderer.text(this.getAttribute('SomeAttributeType') + ": <b>" + symbol + this.getAttribute('SomeAttributeValue') + suffix + "</b><br>" + html_comment  , x + 10 + correctionX, y + 10 * 2)
              .attr({
                zIndex: 16
              }).css({
                fillColor: '#fff',
                color: '#000'
              }).add();
            var box = text.getBBox();
            debugger;
            textBG = chart.renderer.rect(box.x - 5, box.y - 5, box.width + 10, box.height + 10, 5)
              .attr({
                fill: '#ffffff',
                stroke: '#0072bc' || 'grey',
                'stroke-width': 1,
                zIndex: 15
              }).add();
          }).on('mouseout', function (event) {
            text.destroy();
            textBG.destroy();
            $('.highcharts-tooltip').show();
```

What I tried till now:
1. I tried to manually wrap it up by inserting \n say every 10 characters. But i saw \n is totally neglected.

2. I tried changing some css as well

   text = chart.renderer.text(this.getAttribute('someAttributeType') + ": **" + symbol + this.getAttribute('someAttributeValue') + suffix + "**
   " + html_comment  , x + 10 + correctionX, y + 10 * 2)
                 .attr({
                   zIndex: 16
                 }).css({
                   fillColor: '#fff',
                   color: '#000',
                   **wordWrap: 'break-word'**
                 }).add();

   textBG = chart.renderer.rect(box.x - 5, box.y - 5, box.width + 10, box.height + 10, 5)
                 .attr({
                   fill: '#ffffff',
                   stroke: '#0072bc' || 'grey',
                   'stroke-width': 1,
                   zIndex: 15,
                   **wordWrap: 'break-word'**
                 }).add();

As you can see above used wordWrap to break word in both renderer.text and rederer.rect. Even above is not working.

Is there a solution to this problem using Highcharts or using a correct css properties?

Comment: Apply word-wrap: break-word;white-space: normal; to that tooltip container.

Comment: Hi murali, i did that(see my comments) still it is not wrapping up

Comment: Live demo to work with would be great. Anyway, remember that Highcharts lib is using SVG/VML to render texts, not HTML. Instead of using `\n` try to use `<br>` tags. Also there should be `"word-wrap"` not `"wordWrap"`. And for the `renderer.rect` word wrapping doesn't make sense ;) And small suggestion: have you tried to use `renderer.label` ? Not officla API, but check stackoverflow for examples. It supports background and HTML.

Comment: Renderer.label gives you word wrap simply by adding a CSS width property: http://jsfiddle.net/8N3Sz/18/